# How to select same Range in multiple sheets in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having 4 Sheets, say...,

```
 STP1
 STP2
 STP3
 STP4
 STP5
```

I want to update all D3 cells of all the 5 sheets at same time.

I am trying in this way..,

```
  Worksheets(Array("STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4", "STP5")).Select
  Worksheets(Array("STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4",   "STP5")).Range("D3").Select
  If Worksheets(Array("STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4", "STP5").Range("D3").Offset(0, 0) = "" Then
  Worksheets(Array("STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4", "STP5")).Range("D3").Select.End(xlDown).Select
  End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = Eng
```

But this is not working out...
Can anyone please help me here...

Comment: Looping through all sheets is not good ?

Comment: You mean it is good?? But here I need to write code 5 times.. so tring these way

Comment: see code in my answer below (don't think it's too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code too long (looping through all Sheets), using a `Select Case` where you can add as many sheets as you like.

(It is better to avoid selecting cells)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectSheets()

Dim Sht             As Worksheet

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case Sht.Name
        Case "STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4", "STP5"

            If Sht.Range("D3") = "" Then
                Sht.Range("D" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Eng
            Else
                Sht.Range("D3").Value = Eng
            End If

    End Select

Next Sht

End Sub
```

Comment: @SwethaReddy you're welcome, thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets(Array("STP1", "STP2", "STP3", "STP4", "STP5")).Select
    Sheets("STP1").Activate
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "whatever"
End Sub
```

*(but I would use a loop and no `Selects`)*